# How to keep application in background(minimized) on device after booting complete

Tags: android, background, background-service, bootcompleted

I am newbie to android  and I am implementing background service im my app, i am starting app on  BOOT_COMPLETED process & i am calling the activity to start the app and app come on foreground. But i want to keep the app in background (Minimized) and i want to do slient login in app.
i am using below code for app start on Boot_Complete.

```
public class bootUpLocation extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        // here we start the service
        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast receiver start for location",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want to start, but not show the LoginActivity class, is that right ? If it is, then you should use a service and not an activity

Comment: use a service not an activity